# Spring Security authentication logging

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security, log4j

I am using Spring Security 3.1 to authenticate users for a website.  When a login fails because spring security is unable to connect to the database, I get the following statement in my log:

```
2012-07-12 11:42:45,419 [ajp-bio-8009-exec-1] DEBUG      org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

My question is, why is this a DEBUG statement instead of an ERROR?  I have to wade through a whole lot of debug statements just to find the actual error.

EDIT

Here is my authentication manager:

```
<bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/securityDS"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service 
            data-source-ref="securityDataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM login WHERE username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM login WHERE username = ?"
        />        
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That message is printed out in `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.unsuccessfulAuthentication`:

```
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Authentication request failed: " + failed.toString());
```

There are a number of ways an authentication can fail, including based on user input.   For example, in `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate`, a `BadCredentialsException` could be thrown if the username is not found:

```
        try {
            user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
            logger.debug("User '" + username + "' not found");

            if (hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                        "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            } else {
                throw notFound;
            }
        }
```

Since there could be legitimate reasons why an authentication can fail, it doesn't make sense for `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` to log an error.   If there is a system error the error should have been logged further downstream.

I suspect that the problem is in `DaoAuthenticationProvider` (see my comment inline):

```
protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    UserDetails loadedUser;

    try {
        loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
    }
    catch (DataAccessException repositoryProblem) {
        // *** ERROR SHOULD BE LOGGED HERE ***
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(repositoryProblem.getMessage(), repositoryProblem);
    }
```

Perhaps an error should be logged here - you can log a JIRA with Spring to request that.    Though maybe they are assuming that everyone is going to provide a custom `UserDetailsService` and will catch/log their own exceptions there.  If you are using `JdbcDaoImpl` it does not.   I think `JdbcDaoImpl` is intended to be an example and is not robust.  Per the docs:

> The good news is that we provide a number of UserDetailsService
>   implementations, including one that uses an in-memory map
>   (InMemoryDaoImpl) and another that uses JDBC (JdbcDaoImpl). Most users
>   tend to write their own, though, with their implementations often
>   simply sitting on top of an existing Data Access Object (DAO) that
>   represents their employees, customers, or other users of the
>   application.

Comment: How do I find out what kind of UserDetailService I am using?

Comment: Can you post the `<authentication-manager>` section of your config?

Comment: Yes, `<security:jdbc-user-service>` is `JdbcDaoImpl`.  So basically if you want better error logging you'll need to write your own `UserDetailsService`.   The good news is that it's super easy to do so - there is only one method that you need to implement (`loadUserByUsername`).

Comment: So I'd have to throw out the convenience and dependability of Spring Security's out-of-the-box implementation and use my own just for the sake of getting better logging for login failures?  That sounds like a waste of time... not to mention opening the door for introducing new bugs.

Comment: In this case it is better logging for situations where your DB connection is incorrect/the DB is down, etc.   You have to decide what's more important for your situation.  I would recommend taking a look at the source of `JdbcDaoImpl` to see how it works.

Comment: The latest version [uses](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L341) `logger.trace` now.

Answer (score 18):

My solution:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationEventListener.class);

   @Override
   public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent authenticationEvent) {
      if (authenticationEvent instanceof InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
         // ignores to prevent duplicate logging with AuthenticationSuccessEvent
         return;
      }
      Authentication authentication = authenticationEvent.getAuthentication();
      String auditMessage = "Login attempt with username: " + authentication.getName() + "\t\tSuccess: " + authentication.isAuthenticated();
      logger.info(auditMessage);
   }

}
```

No other configurations are required.

Comment: Where do you add the AuthenticationEventListener in the config ? Does it have to be built into the main web-app jar file ?

Comment: I have managed to use the logger with JDBC using something like this:
<bean id="authLogger"    class="org.geowebcache.security.AuthenticationEventListener">
     <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
     </property>
 </bean>