# Configure Spring Security to only log the Exception without Stacktrace?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, logging, spring-security

I like to have Spring Security log what's going so

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug
```

is enabled.

However, when a user uses bad credentials or is not activated, each time an exception with about fifty lines of (uselesss) Stacktrace is logged.

I'd like to get only the exception

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException: User is disabled
```

without stacktrace.If the logging level is set to info, there however is no log if there was an logging attempt at all.

Is that possible? - without disabling exceptions at all

Comment: What looging framework do you use? Logback? Log4j?

Comment: this sounds similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17696767/1211547